# Firebase import users from existing app

Tags: firebase

How do I import an existing app's users into firebase's Simple Login with email / password.

I have keys and hashes and a user collection with user data. Is it possible to just import it or do I have to use firebase's user api.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about that: http://bettysteger.com/migrating-users-from-parse-to-firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current best way to import existing user accounts from another service into Firebase for use within Firebase Simple Login is to call `createUser(email, password, callback)` for each of the email address / password combinations, provided you have them. There is currently no out-of-the-box way to import user email addresses and password *hashes* into Firebase Simple Login, though ping support@firebase.com and there may be a way to do this.

If you already have an existing authentication mechanism that you'd like to continue using, rather than using Firebase Simple Login, check out [custom token generation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html), which will allow you to continue using your existing authentication. This would require you to generate a JSON Web Token (JWT) when each user authenticates, and this token's payload could then be used in your security rules, as described here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html.

Comment: Is there way how to import/export users from one Firebase to another? Thank you

Comment: @Casero Not presently.

Answer (score 2):

**Update as of 11/2019**

1. Very first step, make sure to install Firebase Tools, the command for this `npm install -g firebase-tools`, I assume that you have installed `Node.js` and `npm` before.
2. Hit in your terminal `firebase login` to log in to the account from which you want to export (you might be already logged in btw).
3. Export your emails and password by using `firebase auth:export database.json --project projectName`.
4. Now `firebase logout` and `firebase login` to the account where you want to import.
5. Go to `Console` -> `Project` -> `Authentication` -> `Password hash parameter` of the project **from which you're exporting** (this is very important, if you'd take parameters from that one to which you import it won't work).

There you can see something like that:

```
hash_config {
  algorithm: SCRYPT,
  base64_signer_key: <long string of random characters>,
  base64_salt_separator: <short string of random characters>,
  rounds: 8,
  mem_cost: 14,
}
```

6. In your terminal run `firebase auth:import database.json --hash-algo=scrypt --rounds=8 --mem-cost=14 --hash-key=<long string of random characters> --salt-separator=<short string of random characters> --project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME`. Note: I didn't use quotes for the strings and it worked out perfectly.
7. Test your authentication if it works on new environment. Might be obvious, but don't forget to change your `firebaseConfig` to be on the new project :)

**Edit:**

To clarify on which Firebase Tools version it works:

```
$ firebase --version
7.6.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to export/import users in Firebase v3.x. All you have to do is install Firebase CLI (Firebase Tools), setup a folder on your machine representing tooling mirror for your Firebase project. (as simple as `firebase init` in the appropriate folder)

To Export: [auth:export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport)

To Import: [auth:import](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#import_user_accounts)

**Update:** At the time I wrote this answer, given example in link above for `auth:import` has 2 pieces missing: `hash key` and `salt separator`, which you can ask from customer support. Maybe they share it with tools or from console in the future.